# Istio Gateway not being applied to istio-ingressgateway

Tags: istio

I'm trying to make istio work with my mssql service. The istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer doesn't seems to be updated with the correct port value.

I'm running on GKE on 1.10+

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql
  labels:
    app: mssql
    service: mssql
spec:
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: public-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 1433
      protocol: TCP
      name: tcp-1433
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vservice-mssql
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - public-gateway
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 1433
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mssql
        port: 
          number: 1433
```

After applying the configuration on running I expected to have the port open on the `istio-ingressgateway` but I'm having this as a result:

```
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.8.1.100   **REDACTED** 80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:30160/TCP,8060:32736/TCP,853:30641/TCP,15030:31124/TCP,15031:30849/TCP   90d
```

The port I opened on the gateway is not listed.

Comment: I think I got it. This is internal. I have to manually edit the istio-ingressgateway config to add new ports. I'm waiting to have a tested solution to post here.

Comment: Hi @Luc, could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as approved? It may help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use following resources def

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql
  labels:
    app: mssql
    service: mssql
spec:
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: public-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 15011
      protocol: TCP
      name: tcp-15011
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vservice-mssql
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - public-gateway
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 15011
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mssql
        port: 
          number: 1433
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: mssql
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: mssql`enter code here`
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
```

Use Node Port 30160 to access mssql

**15011:30160/TCP**

```
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.8.1.100   **REDACTED** 80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:30160/TCP,8060:32736/TCP,853:30641/TCP,15030:31124/TCP,15031:30849/TCP   90d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed istio using the operator, you have to manually add ports to the operator spec:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio-control-plane
spec:
  values:
    ingressGateways:
      - enabled: true
        name: istio-ingressgateway
        k8s:
          service:
            ports:
              - name: status-port
                port: 15021
                targetPort: 15021
              - name: http2
                port: 80
                targetPort: 8080
              - name: https
                port: 443
                targetPort: 8443
              - name: tcp
                port: 31400
                targetPort: 31400
              - name: tls
                port: 15443
                targetPort: 15443
              - # ADD PORTS HERE
```

Those ports listed here are the default ports. I'm not sure if you remove them, if istio-operator will "merge" the default ports with the ones you will add. But you can try that out (let us know!)